# Visualization of multiple classes based on one raster band with Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, visualisation

I'm working with Google Earth Engine and I have a raster image with one band and pixel values between 0 and 2. I want to create three classes:

- class 1: pixel value = 0
- class 2: pixel value = 0.01 - 0.99
- class 3: pixel value = 1 - 2

The first class should be shown in green, the third in blue and the second should be a gradient from light to dark red.
Now my question: How can I map this in one layer?

I have made a few attempts, but nothing has worked. The first attempt has the problem that the classes have no range. The problem with the second attempt is that I created three layers (each for each class) but I need one layer for all classes. Also the combination of .gt and .lt doesn't seem to work.

```
// First attempt:

var test_color =
'<RasterSymbolizer>' +
  '<ColorMap type="values">' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#16ff21" quantity="0" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#ff1e0b" quantity="0.5" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#0e00fc" quantity="1" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#0e00fc" quantity="1.5" />' +
    '<ColorMapEntry color="#0e00fc" quantity="2" />' +
  '</ColorMap>' +
'</RasterSymbolizer>';

Map.addLayer(example.select('VV').sldStyle(test_color), {}, 'Image 1');


// Second attempt:

var class1 = example.updateMask(example.lte(0));
Map.addLayer(class1.select('VV'), {palette: 'green'}, 'Class 1 = 0');

var class2 = example.updateMask(example.gt(0.5).lt(1));
Map.addLayer(class2.select('VV'), {palette: ['#ffb7ad', '#b81400']}, 'Class 2 = 0-1');

var class3 = example.updateMask(example.gte(1));
Map.addLayer(class3.select('VV'), {palette: 'blue'}, 'Class 3 > 1');
```

I created an example image in the script [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ea20a473639a7a0a5b526894c987e147). This calculation of the image doesn't make sense and has other values. It's only for illustration, since the idea remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow you complete, but I think the hack below could do the trick. It sort of classifies the `VV` band. There are three options: `x = 0`, `0 < x < 1`, and `x = 1`. These values then get remapped, spread out, so it can be styled with a regular palette.

Here's how the visualization works:

- `-1` to `0` get `green` to `green`. `x = 0` will get remapped to `0`.
- `0` to `1` get `green` to `#ffb7ad`. There will be no values here.
- `1` to `2` get `#ffb7ad` to `#b81400`. `0 < x < 1` will get remapped to this range.
- `2` to `3` get `#b81400` to `blue`. There will be no values here.
- `3` to `4` get `blue` to `blue`. `x = 1` will get remapped to `3`.

---

```
var s1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-02-20')
  .first()

var image = s1.select('VV')
var classification = image
  .where(image.lte(0), 0)
  .where(image.gte(1), 1)
  
var visualization = classification
  .where(classification.gt(0), classification.add(1))
  .where(classification.gte(1), classification.add(2))
  
Map.addLayer(classification, null, 'classification', false)    
Map.addLayer(visualization, {min: -1, max: 4, palette: 'green,green,#ffb7ad,#b81400,blue,blue'}, 'visualization')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/17133bbc524bccdb2d2275e3966cff0f